# How to identify which nodes left cluster in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

I am trying to find if any API or options are available with elasticsearch cluster to find the list of nodes which are down.

I can currently see the status and nodes which are part of the cluster. But how do  we find if couple of servers are down and left the cluster.

Comment: I don't know if there is an elasticsearch way of doing it, but in my case I use monit to monitor the elasticsearch service on each server and send alerts in case the service stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hit `http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats`, Please refer Node API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html for more information, it will list the nodes which are currently online.

To know the offline nodes, I don't think there is any API, you can use monitor tools like `Nagios` to see if any node is currently down.

Comment: I have that information, I was trying to find out whether elasticsearch is providing any information about the nodes which are offline.

Comment: No, I don't think they provide this.. it would be very difficult to get the information about the nodes which are offline